# get_context_data variable doesn't show up at HTML file

Tags: python, html, django

I have just started with using Django with a Django Crash Course book and got stuck on a part.

Let me show you what I have done so far and where I got stuck.
I opened a templates folder on the hellodjango project folder and wrote some basic HTML code like this.

```
<h1>Greetings</h1> 
<p>Hello, world!</p>
<p>{{my_statement}}</p>
```

Here, the book says that it is okay to write my_statement like this because it will be later understood in python.

Later on it tells you to change views.py file under the homepage folder like this.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class HomepageView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'index.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['my_statement'] = "Nice to see you:"
    return context
```

However, when I refresh the page my_statement variable doesn't show up on the webpage at all. What could I possibly be doing wrong? I think if I didn't didn't have the packages, an error would pop up? But errors don't show up as well.

I have also checked the django documentation on this topic but the code here has similarities to the one I am working with.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i see no error, you're well into index.thml ?

Comment: Your view contains a syntax error, since you start with a single quote `'`, and you end with a double quote `"`.

Comment: Sorry I don't get the question. But if you're asking if the files is named index.html then yes it is.

Comment: I don't think that's what is causing error but up there " *'Nice to see you:"*" you used single quote and double one which makes return to return nothing

Comment: @Villem Van Onsem I just changed it but still nothing gets shown up on the bottom of the page I just think I pasted it wrong here let me edit the question.

Comment: show me your entire index.html file.

Comment: The first part of the code is the entire index.html file :d

Comment: Is that the actual indentation in your file? The `def get_context_data()` and subsequent definition needs to be indented, otherwise it won't be understood as being a method of the `HonepageView` class.

Comment: Yes that's the actual indentation. Are you suggesting I should put the function under the class? I got an indentation error when I tried to do that. Maybe I did the indentation wrong again, but I think that's very unlikely.

Comment: Well that's the problem. Just indent that function, so the `def` line is level with the `template_name = 'index.html'`, and the body of the method indented further. You say this came from a book, surely that shows the correct indentation? Indentation is critical in Python, if you're not comfortable with that then unfortunately you're going to struggle.

Comment: Yeah, now I get it. You were so right. It showed up right now. I thought the function wasn't supposed to be inside the class that's why I intended it like that. Thank you so much.